# LINQ из выражения в точечную нотацию

Tags: c#, .net, linq, лямбда-выражение

Есть классы моделей

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо получить всех клиентов, у которых были заказы, превосходящие по сумме величину value

Я сделал следующий запрос

```
       var customers = from c in dataSource.Customers
                        from o in c.Orders
                        where o.Total > value
                        select c).Distinct();
```

Выводит то что нужно.

Необходимо выполнить данный запрос в точечной нотации, я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
        var customers = dataSource.Customers.Select(c => c.Orders
                                                        .Where(o => o.Total > value))
                                                        .Distinct();
```

и получается, что запрос возвращает  `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Order>>`, а мне необходим `IEnumerable<Customers>`. 
Скажите пожалуйста в каком месте я ошибаюсь, и как делать запросы подобного вида правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно написать так:

```
var customers = dataSource.Customers.Where(c => 
    c.Orders.Any(o => o.Total > value)).Distinct();
```

Если нужно чтобы хотя бы один заказ больше `value`, или так:

```
var customers = dataSource.Customers.Where(c => 
    c.Orders.All(o => o.Total > value)).Distinct();
```

Если нужно чтобы все заказы больше `value`.

В данном случае не стоит использовать метод `Select`, так как он возвращает новую коллекцию.

Answer (score 3):

Два `from` подряд, в `query` форме соответствуют методу [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx)

Запрос может принять вид:

```
var customers = dataSource.Customers
                          .SelectMany(c => c.Orders, (c,o) => new {c, o})
                          .Where(item => item.o.Total > value)
                          .Select(item => item.c)
                          .Distinct();
```